# Install Ubuntu on SSD along Windows (not HDD)

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

So I have a dual disk system (HDD and SSD). There is already a windows on the SSD and I want to install a ubuntu along side it (not delete the windows).

[image]

but when choosing 'install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager' in the installation type menu, Ubuntu only wants to install itself on the HDD:

[image]

My question is: how to get Ubuntu installing on the SSD (alongside windows)?
(get the same slider as in the image above but for the SSD partition)

Comment: there is no free space in the ssd, shrink your biggest ntfs partition (p4).

Comment: Can you do that from the USB disk or should it be done from windows? (I do not have admin rights on that winbox)

Comment: that would be weird to install another os where you don't have admin right on the installed os, BACKUP and GET READY TO USE THE BACKUP. Yes, gparted, you can shrink it there. I believe you also can  do it ( shrink and install ubuntu) with advanced setup.

Comment: I meant on the windows on that box...

Comment: **Do not shrink the NTFS volume from Ubuntu if you are running Windows 10 with the latest updates**... MS has made changes to NTFS that NTFS-3G doesn't know how to handle.

Comment: @AndroidDev: thanks! Will ask the sysadmin to do it from windows tomorrow then;~

Comment: @AndroidDev Oh! I did not know that, could you point me to an article or something?

Comment: @Artyom - https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/539h9k/ntfs3g_unsupported_reparse_point_after/ Supposedly, it's fixed, but Ubuntu hasn't upgraded to the latest version of NTFS-3G where they fixed it.